# Как записать и считать данные в текстовик находящийся в памяти телефона? Android 5.1.1. Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, файлы, запись

Вот что у меня тут:

```
public void AddClick (View v) {
        // проверяем доступность SD
        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"SD-карта не доступна: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SD-карта не доступна: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
            //return;
        }
        // получаем путь к SD
        File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // добавляем свой каталог к пути
        sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+"mynewdir");
        // создаем каталог
        sdPath.mkdirs();
        // формируем объект File, который содержит путь к файлу
        File sdFile = new File(sdPath, "words.txt");
        try {
            // открываем поток для записи
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sdFile));
            // пишем данные
            bw.write("Содержимое файла на SD");
            // закрываем поток
            bw.close();
            Toast.makeText(this,"Файл записан на SD: " + sdFile.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Файл записан на SD: " + sdFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Почему-то оно не работает. Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: 1)Пересмотрите логи. Если там есть что-то интересное прикрепите к вопросу.

Comment: 2)Возможно у вас нету разрешения в manifest для записи данных на устройство <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @Maks у меня действительно не было этого разрешения, теперь все работает, спасибо) Если хотите вы можете это написать как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропишите в Manifest.xml это разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

для добавления данных в файл без перезаписи используйте это:

```
 public static void usingBufferedWritter() throws IOException {
String textToAppend = "Happy Learning !!";

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FilePath, true));  
writer.newLine();   //Добавляем новую строку
writer.write(textToAppend);
writer.close();
}
```

Comment: Кстати не подскажите как вместо перезаписи файла что-то в него дозаписать? Допустим в нем уже было что-то написано, и надо что-то добавить к этому написаному.

Comment: И еще. С какой версии андроида работает вот этот мой запрос: `// проверяем доступность SD
            if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                    Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"SD-карта не доступна: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SD-карта не доступна: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
                //return;
            }`

Comment: @rfvgy Если мне не изменяет гугл то Environment доступно везде(minimum API level 1)  так же как и Toast

Comment: я ведь правильно понял что этот код должен запросить разрешение на память в виде диалогового окна?

Comment: почему-то когда я делаю дозапись вашим методом файл всеравно перезаписывается, просто начинается запись не с первой, а со второй строки. Помогите пжл